# Play a file to specific channel in a confbridge (asterisk) so that other channels in the conference cannot hear

Tags: asterisk

I have 3 channels in a confRoom (using confbridge in asterisk), now I mute 2 channels so that only one channel at a time is able to talk, Now I want that all the channels who are muted get whispered or informed by playing any file that they are being muted.

There is an option in confbridge 'toggle_mute' which plays conf-mute file when a channels gets muted in a confbridge but this works only on the dtmf event, I am not muting the channel on any dtmf event hence it's not useful for me.
Please suggest me any other way so that I can play a file to a specific channel in a confbridge so that other channels cannot hear that file.

I will be really grateful for any kind of suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you have the control for these calls.. so you could trigger them with a delay and sequentially mute out.. Otherwise another way would be to use BackgroundDetect/WaitForNoise and wait for a specific noise event after muting.. and muting could be done in a time based manner

Comment: Thanks for your response. Finally I have written a patch for confbridge and now I can handle it easily..